# Installing JS library

Tags: javascript, symfony, dhtmlx

I would like to install a third party library in a project using Symfony2, the library is [dHtmlx](http://dhtmlx.com/) and got CSS files, images, and JS files.

I don't understand how can I do. The library must be visible on all website's pages so I can't put it in a Bundle.

Another problem: Css files have references to images files so I can't separate CSS files from images.

Comment: You can include the library in your master page

Comment: see it http://docs.dhtmlx.com/spreadsheet__prog_guide_installing.html

Comment: @RafaelDiaz I don't understand where I should put dHtmlx files in Symfony2's folders (I've already installed the library in another project out of Symfony, so I know how to install external libraries in a project)